# Randomly sample columns of a matrix with replacement, then sample elements of a vector in the same order - R

Tags: r, random

I am performing a bootstrap analysis of community similarity values. I have a matrix of species counts, where the columns represent unique samples, and the rows unique species. Here is an example:

```
#generate a matrix with 20 columns, 30 rows, random values
set.seed(69) #for reproducibility.
otu <-matrix(rpois(20*30, lambda = 2), ncol=20)
```

I have two vectors that are environmental covariates associated with the unique samples. Therefore, each of these vectors is length 20.

```
v1 <- rnorm(20)
v2 <- rnorm(20)
```

I want to create a new species observation matrix that randomly samples the columns of the `otu` matrix, with replacement. I can do this fairly easily.

```
#randomnly sample the columns of the otu matrix with replacement.
otu.boot <- otu[,sample(ncol(otu),size=ncol(otu),replace=TRUE)]
```

My question is, how can I sample vectors `v1` and `v2` in the same order as the randomly sampled with replacement matrix?

Comment: `myOrder <- sample(ncol(otu),size=ncol(otu),replace=TRUE)` and then `otu.boot <- otu[, myOrder]` and `v1[myOrder]` followed by `v2[myOrder]`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @lmo's suggestion in the comments:

```
#establish a sample order with replacement.
 myOrder <- sample(ncol(otu), replace = T)

#go ahead and submsample both the otu matrix and vectors in that order.
otu.boot <- otu[,myOrder]
 v1.boot <-  v1[myOrder]
 v2.boot <-  v2[myOrder]
```